# Simplest way to provide visitor with "Post on my blog" HTML code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a simple JS-webpage: http://zhilkin.com/socio_en.html and would like to provide visitors with the option of copying a piece of text (e.g. their sociotype description) with a link to this page to post on their blog, home page, etc.

For example, the visitor reads a sociotype description and clicks a link/button. I'd like to display something like this on the same page or in a pop-up window:

> Copy/paste this HTML code to your blog:
>
> ```
> <p>...<p>
> <a href="...">
> ```

I've come across such functionality on some websites, but failed to find any guides or examples. Any information, advice, links will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it will help you

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="popOpen();">Popup</button>​
```

**JS**

```
function popOpen()
{
    var myWindow=window.open ("", "","width=350,height=250");
    var content="Copy/paste this HTML code to your blog:";
    content+="<textarea style='width:300px;height:100px;margin:10px 0;border:none;'><p>This is 'myWindow'</p>\n\n<a href='http://google.com'>Link</a></textarea>";
    myWindow.document.write(content);
    myWindow.focus();
}​
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WZtLc/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, get a 0/1 for each option put into a string..

Suppose the first 4 options I picked the left option, and for the rest I chose the right, that string would look like this: 0000111111111111

Once you have that string, you can show them a box with the following text in it:

```
http://zhilkin.com/socio_en.html?preload=0000111111111111
```

Of course, the 0000111111111111 changes depending on what values they have chosen, so update that box with a new link any time one changes.

Finally, you need a little bit of PHP to read that "preload" variable and generate pre-chosen options based on it, where each character is an option.

For a pure JavaScript version, use the HASH. The URL would end up looking like this:

```
http://zhilkin.com/socio_en.html#0000111111111111
```

Upon load you'd get the options using window.location.hash, and when you change your options you'd update that link with the new string of values by setting window.location.hash. This would be retained when people pass around that URL.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not exactly what I'm after. I've edited the question in case it was unclear.

Comment: Ah. What I said is how to generate the link and parse the link. The rest of the stuff is rather easy. You have your framework..

`<p>DESCRIPTION</p>
<a href='LINK'>Check out my SocioType</a>`

Now just generate a description (by checking the values of all the options any time one changes and constructing a sentence out of them), and plug it in. The link I explained how to generate should be put in where it says LINK. It might end up looking like this:

`<p>My Sociotype is like Leonardo DiVinci's</p>
<a href='http://zhilkin.com/socio_en.html#00010010010'>Check out my SocioType</a>`